# Jfoenix 9 and fontawesome

Tags: eclipse, scenebuilder, java-11, jfoenix

I am attempting to import jfoenix 9 into scene builder. However, when I import a new jar file there are no components to import.

Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
JDK 11.0.9
JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The old Scene Builder won't recognise jars built with newer Java versions. Get a current version from [Gluon Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/)